# Hong Kong: Visa for Multiple Entries?

Tags: visas, hong-kong, canadian-citizens, multiple-entry, irish-citizens

I will be travelling to Hong Kong in a few months' time. I hold dual nationality and neither of my nationalities requires a visa to enter Hong Kong. During my trip, I will travel to Korea for a few days, before returning to Hong Kong to fly home.

Will I require a visa as I will have multiple entries within 3 months of first arriving in Hong Kong, or does visa-free entry allow me to come and go (as a tourist), effectively, as I please?

I'm guessing that using my two passports would be something they would spot instantly and lead to further questions?

Comment: Which nationalities? It might make a difference.

Comment: Canada and Ireland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should encounter absolutely no problems.  Hong Kong immigration are both efficient and pleasant.

I have resided in Hong Kong for over 9 years and hold permanent residency.  We receive both family and business visitors who regularly tour the surrounding region.

Recently a colleague holding a Thai passport entered HK on the 4 June, left for Dubai on 5 June, returned on 19 June, left for Macau on 24 June returned to HK on 25 June and departed HK yesterday.

They did not hold a visa, and at no point were they questioned or challenged as to their purpose of visit and/or frequency of entry/exit.

Upon each entry you will be granted the amount of visa free days applicable to your passport.  These can be chained together and there is no limit on the total number of days you can stay in one year, as long as you always exit and re-enter before each visa free period expires, and do not take paid employment or engage in other activities prohibited by your tourist status. My only advice would be to stick to one passport.